# Trying to get data from a site through an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am trying to get data from [this site](http://food2fork.com/about/api) . These are my controller ,model and view :

model:

```
 require 'httparty'
 class Recipe
 include HTTParty
 default_options.update(verify: false)
 ENV["FOOD2FORK_KEY"] = 'c1dfc441de0f628c2fa35f03320957a3'
 default_params key: ENV['FOOD2FORK_KEY']
 hostport = ENV['FOOD2FORK_SERVER_AND_PORT'] || 'www.food2fork.com'
 base_uri "http://#{hostport}/api/search?"
 format :json

 def self.for term
 get("", query: { query: term})["recipes"]
 end
end
```

controller :

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search_term = params[:looking_for] || 'chocolate'
    @recipes = Recipe.for(@search_term)
  end
end
```

view:

```
<p>Powered By Food2Fork.com</p>
<%= @search_term%>
<% if (@recipes.nil?) %>
<h2>Cant find recipe</h2>

<% else %> 
<table border="1">
 <tr>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Rank</th>
 </tr>
 <% @recipes.each do |course| %>
 <tr class=<%= cycle('even', 'odd') %>>
    <td><%= link_to(image_tag(course["image_url"], height: '100', width: '100'), course["f2f_url"])%></td>
    <td><%= link_to(course["title"], course["f2f_url"]) %></td>
    <td><%= course["social_rank"] %></td>
 </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>
<% end %>
```

My program has no bugs but it always has the some output , it does not matter the `search_term` is and I dont know what to try anymore. Am I using the API wrong? :/

If you give me a MINUS please comment what I did wrong so I can improve myself. Thank you.

Comment: what is the url you are visiting on your app to trigger the search?

Comment: don't you need to pass `base_uri` to `get` method?

Comment: The url is : localhost:3000/recipes/index?looking_for=mocha

Comment: @mr_sudaca i am new to ruby_on_rails , i dont understand the question ;/

Comment: A tip: you should be able to determine whether the problem you are having is in the model, the controller or the view (hint: `Rails.logger.debug term`). Then post only the relevant code in the question (nobody really cares how do you style your `tr` tags). It will remove the clutter and get your question more attention.